# CollectionView ItemsLayout vertical spacing issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, observablecollection

Recently I changed a collectionview by setting its VerticalItemSpacing property to have a preseted value, it seemed to work fine but just noticed that when some new element is added, the spacing between it and penultimate one is zero until I scroll the view. When I back to the last element again, the space between them appears. Is this a known issue? some one knows a fix for that?

my data templates are grids with boxviews inside(for simulating a background since frames were seeing to be more expensive) and this is my ItemsLayout property:

```
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalItemSpacing="3" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

Comment: I test it in my xamarin forms, If I add the items to the `CollectionView` it worked as normal. My Xamarin forms nuget package is `4.6.0.726` Here is my running GIF.  https://imgur.com/a/E2PfB1c

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT the issue seems to appear only when the penultimate element fits screen(horizontally). I have 15 possible data templates, I noticed that every time it occurs the penultimate one fits screen.

Comment: Could you provide a demo about this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT you can download it here 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/179677b2a2fe1f5bfd6ac5daef28055620200611192154/765d9c

The file you have to look is ChatPage.xaml and ChatPage.cs. Also you will see that scrolling is jittering. Actually the main problem is about performance when scrolling. Cause of that I changed my approach and now I have this spacing problem. If you can give me an advice about this too, I would be very thankful.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I almost forget to tell you: this is a really minimal example, so you will only be able to tap the send button and it will add a new element that fits screen horizontally(you will that see it has no space), but if you scroll the view, it the space appears. When the app start, please scroll everything to bottom, for some reason the code that scrolls automatically is not working as it is on the original project, maybe I took off some crucial code.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT hey, sorry for disturbing you, but did you had time to look into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to your `DataTemplate` name of `MapMsgSend`, please check this line

```
  <BoxView Margin="-5,-5,-5,-1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="#dcf8c6" />
```

If you set the Margin to "-5,-5,-5,-1" , it will get the result like this screenshot.

[image]

If I set the margin to `Margin="3"` it worked like following sceenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Leon. You found the problem. Do you think will be better to use frame instead, to get the look I wanted? Since you have read the code, I will also ask you if have a tip to avoid the jittering that I'm experiencing while scrolling these few rows of content.

Comment: Yes, I think `Frame` is a better way(If you have Image and text in a message)

Comment: About jittering, can I open a new question for that? It's really annoying. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Yes of course, If you application have some privacy,  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6  
 to open a free ticket for support.

Comment: This link opens a login form where there is no information, I can see only the login form.

Comment: Can you got the result like this screenshot? https://imgur.com/a/4W11PlT, The first time you open it will be slow, please wait serveral seconds.

Comment: This is screen is showed for less than 1 sec and throws me to the login page.

Comment: I'm seeing your screenshot, very nice. Is this a paid service?

Comment: No, that is free.

Comment: This is a known issue by xamarin team and they don't know when will solve this LOL. 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7152